# Windows 10 Style for JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I'm working on an application that makes use of Swing's `JInternalFrame`. I'm using the native look and feel with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`.

However, the native look and feel for the internal frame remains in the Windows Vista/7 style while running on a Windows 10 machine. With the example code from [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8152961), 
I get the following result (with both `JDK 8` and `JDK 10`):

[image: JInternalFrame on Windows 10]

I assume the styling supplied with Swing hasn't been updated in a long time, so there is no intended way to style the internal frame like a native window on systems newer than Vista. Is there a possible workaround instead?

Comment: A workaround is possible but complicated. You need to provide your own `InternalFrameUI`. This means, that you need to paint the title bar and border by yourself. Then you need to update the UI for internal frame using `UIManager.put("InternalFrameUI", MyWindows10UI.class.getName());`

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried on Windows Server 12 R2 and the rendering is still working on Java 8. On my clients with Win 10 and Java 8 I experienced the same as you :(

Answer (score 1):

In this situation it is good to inspect the UIManager's theme:

```
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    Object[] keys = UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getDefaults().keySet().toArray();
    Arrays.sort(keys, Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (keys[i].toString().startsWith("InternalFrame.")) {
            System.out.println(keys[i] + " : " + javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().get(keys[i]));
        }
    }
```

You'll find the following keys:

```
    "InternalFrame.closeIcon"
    "InternalFrame.iconifyIcon"
    "InternalFrame.maximizeIcon"
    "InternalFrame.minimizeIcon"
```

Then create 4 transparent .png icons for close, iconify, maxize/minimize.

```
private void setInternalFrameIcon(String uiKey, String resource) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(resource));
    UIManager.put(uiKey, close);
}

    setInternalFrameIcon("InternalFrame.closeIcon", "... .png");
    setInternalFrameIcon("InternalFrame.iconifyIcon", "... .png");
    setInternalFrameIcon("InternalFrame.maximizeIcon", "... .png");
    setInternalFrameIcon("InternalFrame.minimizeIcon", "... .png");
```